# SQL Count from different tables in one Query

Tags: sql, count

I assume this was asked already once but I didn't find the right answer unfortunately.

I have multiple tables around customer data and all have the foreign key company_id. My goal is to have a list in which the first column gives me the company_id and the other columns aggregated values (e.g. COUNT) from other table. All grouped by the company_id

For example:

company_id | COUNT(products) | COUNT(purchases)

My approach was something like this but it didn't work out and I can't make up my mind of it (apart from using vlookups in excel)

```
SELECT pro.company_id, COUNT(*)
(SELECT pu.company_id, COUNT(*) FROM purchases pu GROUP BY pu.company_id) as 'COUNT(Purchases)'
FROM products pro
GROUP BY pro.company_id
```

Comment: Skip the GROUP BY in the subqeury, instead put a WHERE clause condition refrencing the pro table.

Comment: Tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you! This was easier than expected... Unfortunately, I didn't understand the union_all approach you suggested me  Hence, I'm happy that this works fine as well

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `union all` and aggregation:

```
SELECT p.company_id, SUM(is_product), SUM(is_purchase)
FROM ((SELECT pr.company_id, 1 as is_product, 0 as is_purchase
       FROM products pro
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT pu.company_id, 0 as is_product, 1 as is_purchase
       FROM purchases pu
      )  pp      
GROUP BY p.company_id
```

Note that this keeps all products in either table, so the results can have `0` counts in one or the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate each table and then join to customer:

```
SELECT com.company_id, "COUNT(Purchases)", "COUNT(Products)"
from companies as com
left join
 (
   SELECT company_id, COUNT(*) as "COUNT(Purchases)"
   FROM purchases 
   GROUP BY company_id
 ) as pu
on com.company_id = pu.company_id
left join
 (
   SELECT company_id, COUNT(*) as "COUNT(Products)"
   FROM products 
   GROUP BY company_id
 ) as pro
```

If there's no row for a customer this displays NULL, if you want to return 0 switch to `coalesce("COUNT(Products)", 0)`

Comment: Thank you! This works well for me :) 
I was wondering what would you do differently if you'd query aggregated values from the companies table and add the COUNT(Purchases) and COUNT(Products) to it?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you try to do, but you can easily add a GROUP BY to the outer select and `sum("COUNT(Purchases)")`

Comment: Okay, let me try this again. It didn't work when I tried to add the GROUP BY to the other select statement. That's why I asked